# Trying to combine all value from jquery.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at my code, I am trying to combine all value from the `jquery.each` to a string like this ok,good, and then passed to ajax value. Appreciate. or `array('ok','good')` acceptable also

```js
var global = {
    "44":["onset","frequency"],
    "45":["onset"]
};
var $val = global[44];
            
jQuery.each( $val, function( key ,value) {  
    var value = $('#'+value).val();   
});
var $combine = ;//not sure how to combine all value like this (ok,good), or array(ok,good) acceptable also
var data= {
    action: 'check_first',
    AjaxFrontNonce : ajax_csky.AjaxFrontNonce,
    combine : $combine
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="onset" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" id="frequency" value="good">
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve. its not clear in question. If you want to combine array values from `global` object like `[onset, frequency]`, then what are you getting from `$('#'+value).val()` in loop ?

Comment: and if you want only value to combine from `44' key from object then there is no need of each loop.

Comment: $('#'+value).val() getting the input hidden value. And I then I want to combine them and then use for ajax value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this working snippet

```js
var global = {
  "44": ["onset", "frequency"],
  "45": ["onset"]
};
var $val = global[44];
var arr = [];
$.each($val, function(key, val) {
  var value = $('#' + val).val();
  arr.push(value);
});

var $combine = arr; //not sure how to combine all value like this (ok,good), or array(ok,good) acceptable also
console.log($combine);
var data = {
  action: 'check_first',
  //AjaxFrontNonce : ajax_csky.AjaxFrontNonce, not defiend
  combine: $combine
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="onset" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" id="frequency" value="good">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var global = {
    "44":["onset","frequency"],
    "45":["onset"]
};

var $val = global[44];
var values = [];  

jQuery.each( $val, function( key ,value) {  
    values.push($('#'+value).val());   
});

var $combine = '(' + values.join(',') + ')';
console.log($combine);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="onset" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" id="frequency" value="good">
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code echo empty (,). Not sure what I did wrong, but other two answer works for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @conan if you run my snippet it works, check your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.map to go over all of the items and return the value for each element.
There is an example of both `Array` and `String` values, you can use whichever works better for you.

```js
var global = {
    "44":["onset","frequency"],
    "45":["onset"]
};
var $val = global[44];

combinedAr = $.map($val, function(val) {
  return $('#'+val).val();
});
combinedStr = combinedAr.join(",");

var data= {
    action: 'check_first',
    AjaxFrontNonce : ajax_csky.AjaxFrontNonce,
    combine : combinedStr
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="onset" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" id="frequency" value="good">
```

Comment: thanks very much. Your code works. But does $.each run faster than $.map.

Comment: I'm not sure if each runs faster than map, however with map you don't need to create a new empty array before looping over the value, the returned value is the array with the data you need.